# Почему исчезает form после появления?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Почему после нажатия на кнопку `show_add_author` форма `add_author` появляется и тут же исчезает?
Мой замысел такой - необходимо, чтобы форма `add_author` изначально была невидима и появлялась после нажатия на кнопку `show_add_author`.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
     <div class="add">
         <form>
             <button id="show_add_author" type="submit">Add author</button>
         </form>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#show_add_author").click(function () {
                    $("#add_author").show();
                });
            });
         </script>
       <form id="add_author" style="display:none">
          <input type="text" name="author_name" placeholder="Enter new author name"/>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит submit формы с кнопкой "show_add_author" и перезагружается страница.

```
<button id="show_add_author" type="button">
```

или

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#show_add_author").click(function () {
    $("#add_author").show();
    return false;
  });
});
```